# Official email validation in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, email-validation

I only want official email addresses such as xyz@company.com to sign up on my service rather than other generic email addresses such as gmail.com or Yahoo mail.com

Is there a ruby gem to achieve this kind of email validation? If not, how to make this happen?

Comment: Just add a negative look ahead's after the `@` and dot `.` symbols. Like (from html5 spec) `(?i)[a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@(?!gmail|yahoo)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?(?:\.(?!gmail|yahoo)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom validation in the appropriate model as shown here: http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-validators-in-ruby-on-rails-4

The basic idea in the article is as follows:

Make your validation method, and put it in a new directory called 'validators'

```
# app/validators/email_validator.rb
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)+@yourdomain.com\z/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "wrong email address")
    end
  end
end
```

(I have not tested this regex! Please use something like http://rubular.com/ and plug in your own email domain pattern to make sure it's working correctly.)

Then make sure Rails knows to load the new validators directory:

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/app/validators/"]
```

Then add the new validation (email) to the appropriate model:

```
#MyModel.rb    
validates :my_email_field, email: true
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a free MailboxValidator web service that you can perform real-time email address validation in Ruby.

https://github.com/MailboxValidator/mailboxvalidator-ruby

```
require "mailboxvalidator_ruby"

apikey = "MY_API_KEY"
email = "example@example.com"

mbv = MailboxValidator::MBV.new()
mbv.apikey = apikey
mbv.query_single(email)

if mbv.error != nil
    puts "Error: #{mbv.error}"
elsif mbv.result != nil
    puts "email_address: #{mbv.result.email_address}"
    puts "domain: #{mbv.result.domain}"
    puts "is_free: #{mbv.result.is_free}"
    puts "is_syntax: #{mbv.result.is_syntax}"
    puts "is_domain: #{mbv.result.is_domain}"
    puts "is_smtp: #{mbv.result.is_smtp}"
    puts "is_verified: #{mbv.result.is_verified}"
    puts "is_server_down: #{mbv.result.is_server_down}"
    puts "is_greylisted: #{mbv.result.is_greylisted}"
    puts "is_disposable: #{mbv.result.is_disposable}"
    puts "is_suppressed: #{mbv.result.is_suppressed}"
    puts "is_role: #{mbv.result.is_role}"
    puts "is_high_risk: #{mbv.result.is_high_risk}"
    puts "is_catchall: #{mbv.result.is_catchall}"
    puts "mailboxvalidator_score: #{mbv.result.mailboxvalidator_score}"
    puts "time_taken: #{mbv.result.time_taken}"
    puts "status: #{mbv.result.status}"
    puts "credits_available: #{mbv.result.credits_available}"
    puts "error_code: #{mbv.result.error_code}"
    puts "error_message: #{mbv.result.error_message}"
end
```